# How to write array formula in VBA syntax (not Excel-Formula)

Tags: vba, excel, syntax, match

To do lookup with two criteria, in Excel-Formula, it would be written as:

```
{MATCH(1, 1*(A1:A5=100)*(B1:B5=150), 0)}
```

How do i write the above formula in VBA syntax for the `WorksheetFunction.Match` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim m As Long

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        m = .Match(1, [1*(A1:A5=100)*(B1:B5=150)], 0)
    End With

    MsgBox m
End Sub
```

[image]

This shows both the array formula in the worksheet and the *VBA* equivalent.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent How to replace, 100 and 150 using variables? I am getting error when I fill those value with variables. Seems not doing concatenation with & right.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough rep to post a comment.. 
This is to aid anyone searching for how to use the answer from "Gary's Student" with variables.  I wrestled with this for over an hour.
The brackets [] used are a shortcut for evaluate(string)
You have to replace those and wrap them in the evaluate method.
Since the parameter is a string, you can construct the string yourself with the variables you need.

```
Sub dural()
Dim m As Long

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    m = .Match(1, evaluate("1*(A1:A5=100)*(B1:B5=150)"), 0)
End With

MsgBox m
```

End Sub

Comment: This is too informative to be a comment! (Not sure what the "evaluate method" means, though...)